# Show that $\int^{R+\delta}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-(x-\delta)^2}\,dx-\int^{R}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx\leq R\delta$, for $0<\delta<R.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> I need to show that, if $0<\delta<R,$ then
>
> $$\int^{R+\delta}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-(x-\delta)^2}\,dx-\int^{R}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx\leq R\delta.$$

The result of evaluating the integrals is awful, and looks pretty hard to handle. Is there an easier way to obtain the result by some bounding argument?

Any hints are much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by letting $t=x-\delta$,
$$\int^{R+\delta}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-(x-\delta)^2}\,dx=
\int^{R}_{-\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt$$
After replacing $x$ with $t$ in the second integral, the given left-hand side can be written as
$$\int^{R}_{-\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt-\int^{R}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt=\int^{\delta/2}_{-\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Since the integrand is symmetric, we have $2\int^{\delta/2}_{0}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt \leq 2\int^{\delta/2}_{0}R\,dt=R\delta.$ Is this train of thought correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You may also say that $\int^{\delta/2}_{-\delta/2}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\,dt \leq \int^{\delta/2}_{-\delta/2}R\,dt=R\delta$.