# A question about estimating an area of overlapping circles

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to show $$\text{Area}((B-B') \cup (B'-B))\leq 4R\delta$$ where B and B' are circles with the same radius R, B is centered at the origin and B' is centered at $(\delta,0)$. Since $B-B'$ and $B'-B$ have the same area and are disjoint, it suffices to show $$\text{Area}(B-B')\leq 2R\delta$$ I have tried looking at triangles, using the implicit equations for the circles, and using the fact that $$\text{Area}(B-B')=\text{Area}(B)-\text{Area}(B\cap B')$$ I have found that $$\text{Area}(B\cap B')\leq 2R(2R-\delta),\quad \text{Area}(B)\leq4R^2$$ I found the first part by overestimating the area of the intersection by a rectangle. If I subtract these two quantities I reach the result, but does not seem like it is exactly allowed the way these inequalities are set up. This is supposed to be part of a proof that a bounded harmonic function is constant for my Analysis of PDE class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required area

$$A = 4.\left(\int_{-R}^{\frac{\delta}{2}}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt - \int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt\right)$$

$$A\le 4.\left(\int_{-R}^{\frac{\delta}{2}}Rdt - \int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{R} Rdt\right)$$

$$A\le 4.R\left(\frac{\delta}{2}+R - R+\frac{\delta}{2}\right)$$

$$A\le4R\delta$$

Answer (score 2):

The following figure shows the upper right quarter of the figure. If you add the red triangular piece to the area of $\>B'\setminus B\>$ you obtain an area which is obviously $=R\cdot\delta$. It follows that the area we are interested in is $<R\delta$, resp. $<4R\delta$ in total.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't use integrals. However, I don't see how if you add the red part to the shaded part it is $R\delta$. Is it because the width of the shaded region is always less than $\delta$ and the height is $R$?

Comment: Every horizontal segment from the inner boundary to the outer boundary has length $\delta$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter (+1) Nice solution by using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle

Answer (score 1):

We have that the area of $(B-B') \cup (B'-B)$ is four times the following 
$$\begin{align}\int_{\delta/2}^{R+\delta}\sqrt{R^2-(t-\delta)^2}dt-\int_{\delta/2}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt
&=
\int_{-\delta/2}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt-\int_{\delta/2}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt\\
&=\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}\sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt\leq R\delta\end{align}$$
where the circles $B$ and $B'$ are given by  $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $(x-\delta)^2+y^2=R^2$.

See also the related question [Show that $\int^{R+\delta}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-(x-\delta)^2}\,dx-\int^{R}_{\delta/2} \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx\leq R\delta$, for $0<\delta<R.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113619/show-that-intr-delta-delta-2-sqrtr2-x-delta2-dx-intr-del/3113624#3113624)